# How to set text coding in the R markdown interactive document?

Tags: r, text, encoding, markdown, shiny

I have problems with text coding in the R markdown interactive document.

I have no specific settings except global text encoding in Tools set to UTF-8.

My code of the document starts with:

````
---
runtime: shiny
output:
  html_document:
    fig_width: 12
    fig_height: 8
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(comment="", message=FALSE, fig.width=12, fig.height=8,tidy.opts=list(keep.blank.line=TRUE, width.cutoff=80),options(width=90))
```


```{r, eval=FALSE}
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("rstudio/dygraphs")
```
````

... and then there is such checkbox

````
```{r}
library(shiny)
checkboxGroupInput("structures",
                         label = h3("Które struktury wyświetlić?"),
                         choices = series_names,
                         selected = series_names)
```
````

and I get such output in bad encdoing. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image: bug]

EDIT: my seesion

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] DT_0.0.4      xts_0.9-7     zoo_1.7-11    dplyr_0.3.0.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1    bitops_1.0-6      DBI_0.3.1        
 [4] devtools_1.6.1    digest_0.6.6      evaluate_0.5.5   
 [7] formatR_1.0       grid_3.1.2        htmltools_0.2.6  
[10] htmlwidgets_0.3.2 httr_0.6.0        knitr_1.8        
[13] lattice_0.20-29   lazyeval_0.1.9    magrittr_1.5     
[16] parallel_3.1.2    Rcpp_0.11.3       RCurl_1.95-4.5   
[19] RJSONIO_1.3-0     rmarkdown_0.3.10  stringr_0.6.2    
[22] tools_3.1.2       yaml_2.1.13
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment, but written as an answer to add graphics and code.

Below your example boiled down to the minimum. The two other chunks are not required. To avoid distraction, this is always recommended when posting here.

````
---
runtime: shiny
output:
  html_document
---

```{r}
library(shiny)
checkboxGroupInput("structures",
                         label = h3("Które struktury wyświetlić?"),
                         choices = c("a","b"),
                         selected = "b")
```
````

When trying to reproduce, I get a similar, but no identical output on my German Windows 7 64 bit:

[image]

When I run it under Linux/RStudio server/Shiny server, everything is fine:

[image]

This might be a bug worth reporting; I had similar problems with German Umlauts before, and the Shiny team has worked really hard to solve it. I suggest to post the output of your system's `sessionInfo()`.

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.2
```